# The meaning of the var I entered is the same. Why do I have different results when running?

Tags: c#

```
var b1;
b1 = true;
Console.WriteLine(b1);
```

If my code runs it throws an error hermit-typed variable must be initialized

```
var b1 = true;
Console.WriteLine(b1);
```

And I do it like this and it compiles normally
I can't understand

Comment: You don't have different results when *running* the first snippet doesn't compile. And it doesn't compile because the language rules don't allow using `var` without an initializer.

Comment: thank for your help .   Because the program is compiled line by line, if there is a problem, it will jump out directly, and the use will report an error directly. Does this mean that?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct `var` required an assignment. Now in your first example your assignment is in another line so the compiler can't deduct the type of the variable `b1` from that.

Instead in your second example the declaration and assignment occur in the same line so the compiler know wich type assign to the `b1` variable.

Comment: how i add you friend   .thank for you